# How to insert custom tag or image inside contentEditable div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is already an answer in stackoverflow that used execCommand(). But as we all know that execCommand has been obsolete [(DOCUMENTATION)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand)

So, How can I change anything or add or modify text or content inside a contentEditable div? As I know medium.com, CKeditor and many other editors use contentEditable to make a editor. How they change/ modify their content?

> It should works like a text editor, select any specific text and then change/ modify or insert new items in it. [Learning purpose]

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  Bold text, italic text, insert images, Heading text, etc
</div>
```